# Twitter Bootstrap drop down menu not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I know there are a lot of questions like this on Stack Overflow and I've looked at them but my dropdown menu still isn't working.

Here's my code:

```html
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
                <div class="navbar-inner">
                        <div class="container">
<ul class="nav pull-left">
<li><a href="#myModal" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="modal" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">Login</a></li>
 <li class="dropdown" id="accountmenu">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">My Account<b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Register</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                        </div>
                </div>
</div>
```

What's wrong with it?

**EDIT**

So the drop down menu is now working with the answer posted to this question. However if I include the scripts mentioned over there the modal window stops working. And when I comment those entries it starts working again.

Here's the code for my modal window:

```html
<div class="modal hide" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
    aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
            X</button>
        <h3 id="myModalLabel">
            Enter your Credentials</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Email</label>
    <div class="controls">
    <input type="email" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="inputPassword">Password</label>
 </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
    <div class="controls">
    <label class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
    </label>
    <a href="news.php" class="btn btn-primary">Login</a>
    <a href="registration.php" class="btn btn-primary">Sign up</a>
    </div>
    </div>
    </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the JavaScript for the trigger:

```js
$('#myModal').on('hide',function(){
    $('.nav > li > a.modal-open-li').removeClass('modal-open-li');
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Seems to work fine in jsFiddle, here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/2hGuv/

You must remember to import the js file.
here is the code with the following files imported:
http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css
http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
            <ul class="nav pull-left">
                <li><a href="#myModal" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="modal" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">Login</a>

                </li>
                <li class="dropdown" id="accountmenu"> <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">My Account<b class="caret"></b></a>

                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Login</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Register</a>

                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey that worked perfectly fine but if I add those scripts my modal window stops working. Any idea why that would be?

Answer (score 19):

For anyone still experiencing this problem. I found that I was including the bootstrap js files twice (I had split my header, body and footer files and had not realised I was including  them both in the footer and header.

Might help someone.

Answer (score 17):

I had a similar problem.
And the cause was the wrong order of js files in head tag.
Correct order is the jquery.min.js first than bootstrap.min.js

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This problem was driving me nuts and this solved my problem. Thanks.

Comment: You saved my day. Thank you very much. This solved my dropdown-toggle and accordion-toggle problems in IE.

Answer (score 11):

Check if you have this in js files: `$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();`

Check if you have something like this with this sequence:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> $(document).ready(function () { $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown(); }); </script>
```

check this: [Bootstrap drop-down menus and tabbable tabs on Docpad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17984224/bootstrap-drop-down-menus-and-tabbable-tabs-on-docpad/17984393#17984393)

Comment: Why the heck wouldn't I have `$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();` in the bootstrap.js file?  I added it manually and it works!  Good find; but why wasn't it there?

Answer (score 11):

Adding this in my ready function fixed the problem for me

```
$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
```

Comment: Hi, after 6 hours of searching finally found this answer and it helped. Thanks.

Comment: Hi again, after adding this solution I realized that the menu is not acting as it should when in collapsed mode ("collapse"). I can see that something happens when I click the button but the menu is not appearing and the menu does not expand downward. Do you have any idea how that can be fixed too?

Comment: Hello, this is my final solution. I hope it helps someone in trouble: /* Starts here */ $(function(){
 $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
 $('.btn.btn-navbar').on('click',function(){
  var $navbar=$($(this).data('target'));
  var height=$navbar.css('height');  
  if(height=='0px'){
   $navbar.css('height','100%');
  }
  else{
   $navbar.css('height','0px');
  }
 })
 
 $('.nav-collapse.collapse').collapse('show');
 
 $('.nav-collapse.collapse ul li a').on('click',function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
 });
}); /* Ends here */

Answer (score 2):

For mine it was because of the order of adding scripts was not right , it should be like this :

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was with version of jQuery.
In bootstrap.js v3.3.6

```
if ((version[0] < 2 && version[1] < 9) || (version[0] == 1 && version[1] == 9 && version[2] < 1) || (version[0] > 2)) {
    throw new Error('Bootstrap\'s JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher, but lower than version 3')
  }
```

Note: **'Bootstrap\'s JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher, but lower than version 3'**

I replaced the code of local jQuery file with jQuery-1.11.3.js and it starts working.

Hope it will work for you as well.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, there was a component over my drop down button, and it took too long for I take note. Noob error, but it may helps somebody.

Comment: This question already has an accepted answer with several answers as well. Try answering some new questions. Cheers

Comment: It was a noob answer and a noob error from my side, but it wasn't a repeated answer... so I thought it was valid...
cheers