# Bootstrap in MVC 4 -> Dropdown doesn`t work

Tags: jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, drop-down-menu

First: I found some topics about this, but they don´t worked for me.
[Twitter Bootstrap drop down menu not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18945899/twitter-bootstrap-drop-down-menu-not-working) , 
[Bootstrap drop-down menus and tabbable tabs on Docpad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17984224/bootstrap-drop-down-menus-and-tabbable-tabs-on-docpad/17984393#17984393)

I built the same page in Netbeans IDE and it worked, but in VS 2013 Ultimate it doesn`t work.

Page:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>TODO supply a title</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
    });

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
        Dropdown
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
        <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a>   </li>
        <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div>TODO write content</div>
</body>
</html>
```

best regards

Comment: do you have errors in your error console of the browser you are working with

Comment: No errors. Bootstrap design works, but when I click on it, nothing happens

Comment: you're js files are loaded successfully? Use firebug to check this

Answer (score 1):

At first view I don't see any mistakes. I created a fiddle with your code and nothing else and its working.

Are you sure that your required js files are loaded succesfully?

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VDesign/61ecg41n/

**HTML**

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
        Dropdown
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
        <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a>   </li>
        <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div>TODO write content</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
});
```

Comment: I installed firebug when I refresh the page the javascripts files are provided from the cache    : Accept-Ranges bytes
Content-Length 67155
Content-Type application/javascript
Date Mon, 22 Dec 2014 14:44:57 GMT
Etag "2136228ec1dd01:0"
Last-Modified Mon, 22 Dec 2014 13:35:32 GMT
Server Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-Powered-By ASP.NET
X-SourceFiles =?UTF-8?B?YzpcdXNlcnNcaGFmLTkyMlxkb2N1bWVudHNcdmlzdWFsIHN0dWRpbyAyMDEzXFByb2plY3RzXFdlYkFQUFxXZWJBUFBcU2NyaXB0c1xib290c3RyYXAuanM=?=

Comment: Built same application in VS 2012 Ultimate and it worked, strange O.o

Comment: Also place all of your js code before the closing body tag at the bottom of your page